# Finding if the group of isometries of a cube is a normal subgroup of $S_{12}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be the group of isometries of a cube and let X be the set of edges of the cube.
This action defines an injective homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow S_{12} $, injective since stabilisers of adjacent edges overlap only at ${e}$.
I am struggling to determine if $Im(\phi)$ is a normal subgroup of $S_{12}$. I have tried considering the action of G on its left cosets and a few other ideas but nothing has yielded useful progress.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Pick an arbitrary nonidentity element of $G$ and find a conjugate of it which is not in $G$. Do you know when two permutations are conjugate?

Comment: Without noting that S_12 has only one normal subgroup, why is it obvious that G is not the union of conjugacy classes?

Comment: Berci's comment answers that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique non-identity proper normal subgroup of $\mathfrak S_{12}$ is the alternating group $\mathfrak A_{12}$.

$G$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak S_{4} \times \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ and therefore has $2 \times 4!= 48$ elements. As $ \vert \mathfrak A_{12} \vert \gt 48$, $\text{Im}(\phi)$ isn't normal in $\mathfrak S_{12}$.